# Unable to create Azure AKS Cluster using existing VNET and Subnets

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I'm trying to build an AKS cluster in Azure using Terraform.  However, I do not want AKS deployed into its own VNET and Subnet, I already have built a subnet within a vnet that I want it to use.  When trying to just give it the subnet ID, I get an overlapping CIDER issue.  My networking is:

VNET: 10.0.0.0/16
Subnets: 10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24, and 10.0.3.0/24.  I need AKS to use the 10.0.1.0./24 subnet within this VNET.  However, my Terraform config is trying to use a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/16, which is an obviouis conflict.  I don't know how to fix this issue inside of Terraform, with the portal I can just choose the vnet/subnet for AKS.  Below is my Terraform configuration which generates the error:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  subscription_id = "####"
  tenant_id       = "####"
}

locals {
  azure_location = "East US"
  azure_location_short = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary_vnet_resource_group" {
  name     = "vnet-prod-002-eastus-001"
  location = local.azure_location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary_vnet_virtual_network" {
  name                = "vnet_primary_eastus-001"
  location            = local.azure_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.primary_vnet_resource_group.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks-subnet" {
  name           = "snet-aks-prod-002-eastus-001"
#  location = local.azure_location
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary_vnet_virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.primary_vnet_resource_group.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
 }

output "aks_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "application-subnet" {
  name           = "snet-app-prod-002-eastus-001"
#  location            = local.azure_location
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary_vnet_virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.primary_vnet_resource_group.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
 }

resource "azurerm_subnet" "postgres-subnet" {
  name           = "snet-postgres-prod-002-eastus-001"
#  location            = local.azure_location
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary_vnet_virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.primary_vnet_resource_group.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
 }

output "postgres_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.postgres-subnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks-prod-002-eastus-001" {
  name                = "aks-prod-002-eastus-001"
  location            = local.azure_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.primary_vnet_resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "aks-prod-002-eastus-001"


  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id

  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  addon_profile {
    aci_connector_linux {
      enabled = false
    }

    azure_policy {
      enabled = false
    }

    http_application_routing {
      enabled = false
    }

    oms_agent {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not a Terraform expert and really need a hand with this if anyone knows how to accomplish this.  I've been up and down the documentation and I can find a way to specify the subnet id but that's about all I can do.  If I don't specify the subnet id then everything is built, but there is a new vnet created which is what I don't want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

All the following properties need to be set under `network_profile` as following:

```
network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
    network_policy = "azure"
    service_cidr = "10.0.4.0/24"
    dns_service_ip = "10.0.4.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
  }
```

These were missed, I hope this helps anyone who is having problems similar to mine.

More info about this block can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#network_plugin